# backbone.js service calls changes the request type

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
[WARN][TiAPI   (  480)]  [REST API] apiCall  [object Object]
[WARN][TiAPI   (  480)]  [REST API TYPE] apiCall  POST
[WARN][TiAPI   (  480)]  [object Object]
[WARN][TiAPI   (  480)]  [REST API] apiCall  [object Object]
[WARN][TiAPI   (  480)]  [REST API TYPE] apiCall  PUT
```

When i first time hit the service, the service gets called with the type POST, but the second time it sends the PUT instead of POST. How can i actually make the request type POST all the time.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone does POST because it doesn't know the specific URL to PUT the thing to. However PUT is the correct method when you know the URL in advance. By default, Backbone uses the "id" property, if present, to build the URL. So without an "id", it assumes you want the server to populate it, like this:

```
=>
POST {"foo":"bar"} /things
<=
200 OK {"foo":"bar","id":"a36f933"}
```

However, if you generate the id on the client, or if you already know the id, Backbone will do a PUT, and assumes that the server will accept it, like this:

```
=>
PUT {"foo":"bar","id":"12345abc"} /things/12345abc
<=
200 OK {"foo":"bar","id":"12345abc"}
```

This is all in accordance with how RESTful URLs are supposed to work and the intent and meaning behind non-idempotent POST requests, versus idempotent PUT requests. If you understand idempotence, Backbone's behavior starts to make sense :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

http://quoderat.megginson.com/2011/11/17/post-put-idempotence-and-self-identification/

Answer (score 1):

Backbone is *by default* using `CRUD` to synchronise with data endpoint. This mean the first API call is a `POST` (for *create* action), and then, on second call, as the modal have an `id`, Backbone will send a `PUT` (for the *update* action)

To force the use of `POST`, you'll need to override [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync).